# Is "sat a horse" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

I came across the phrase "sat a horse" in a novel. I ignored it as a typo, thinking it should have been "I sat on a horse." However I searched this on Google now and I find [a number of examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22sat%20a%20horse%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1981,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en) where this phrase occurs.

Why is this grammatical and what does this mean?

Comment: I read in McCarthy's "Blood Meridian": "The sergeant sat his horse beside him [the captain I presume] ..."
and a couple of lines further:
"Then he sat his horse with the glass at his chest like a crucifix."

Comment: William Melvin Kelley, in his novel *A Different Drummer*, writes: «Harry had sat the horse and watched him».

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To 'sit a horse' means much more than to 'sit upon a horse': it means to adopt and maintain a correct posture and fluidity of motion while riding a horse.

It is usually encountered with a qualification, as:

> She sits a horse very well, very well indeed.
>   Set Lt. Harpeth down for riding lessons. He sits that pony like a demmed Cockney greengrocer.